# How can I mark the current tab's label with a star?

Tags: vim

I have the following for the `guitablabel`

```
set guitablabel=%N/\ %t\ %M
```

I was wondering if there is a way to tweak it so that I have `*` in front of a current tab without defining another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, one cannot simply use `tabpagenr()` to query the current tab page. Apparently, Vim internally switches through the tab pages when evaluating `'guitablabel'`. As a workaround, I use an `:autocmd` to set a tab-scoped variable. With that, one can use a `%{...}` expression to add the asterisk for the current tab page:

```
au TabEnter * let t:current = 1
au TabLeave * let t:current = 0
set guitablabel=%{exists('t:current')&&t:current?'*':''}%N/\ %t\ %M
```